# Change the height propriety on a live website?

Tags: html, css, web-inspector

I am trying to use the built in inspector tool in Google Chrome to manipulate the site http://www.di.se (as it probably has one of the most @ layouts I have ever seen on a popular website) with around 300 000 visitors daily.

It seems to be mainly built with three HTML frame tags with the names: historyFrame, headerFrame and contentFrame. I can remove the headerFrame that covers a huge part of the view. However, I don't know how to change the contentFrame size so that it will cover the entire screen.

I have tried to add a CSS height property but it does not seem to change anything. If this is solvable I would be very thankful and so would 300000 other users :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by:

First deleting the first Frame(header)

and modify this:

from:

```
rows=".260,*"
```

To:

```
rows="1,*"
```

So you have only the frame you want, no useless data and the frame you want take 100% of the screen.

Comment: Thanks! but I am not able to modify that code of some reason. Maybe it has something to do with Chrome's toolkit as mentioned by the previous answer?

Comment: Firefox do it well: inspect element by right click, go to the first frame head node delete it and modify the property given. I tested it with firefox

Answer (score 4):

The `frameset`, which is the parent of the frame you removed, specifies the heights for each of the frames, currently `rows="0,210,*"`. So if you remove the header frame, the content frame becomes the second frame and gets a height of 210. By changing this attribute to `0,*` the problem should be fixed.

However I'm not able to modify this property in Chrome's toolkit. Maybe this is a limitation of the developer tools of Chrome. After all, frames are old (removed even from HTML5), so maybe they didn't pay much attention to supporting it.

Note though that the top frame contains the advertising that probably pays for the site. If you got this working and all 300.000 users would use your solution, then the site would probably seize to exist, and you got 300.000 unhappy users. So think twice before you do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and you are absolutely right regarding the advertising. I  just didn't see it as I have adblock installed :)  I am not able to change the row property ether. I'll try with another browser or inspector toolkit then.

Comment: @GolezTrol, I like the way you see things. sometimes I am to exited to provide answer rather than thinking of consequences.